# VBA web scraping

Tags: excel, web-scraping, html-tableextract, vba

I am trying to get a row of data from this table on this website: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/neog/financials?query=balance-sheet

Now I can manage to get the "total liabilities" row using the

```
doc.getelementsbyclassname("net")(3).innertext
```

but I cannot figure out how to get any other rows of data such as common stock.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range("bscode").Row And _
Target.Column = Range("bscode").Column Then
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & Range("bscode").Value & "/financials?query=balance-sheet&data=quarterly"

Do
 DoEvents

Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document
Dim sD As String
sD = Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(8).innerText

MsgBox sD

Dim aD As Variant
aD = Split(sD, "$")
Range("bs").Value = aD(1)
Range("ba").Value = aD(2)
Range("bb").Value = aD(3)
Range("bc").Value = aD(4)

End If
End Sub
```

If it helps, I have the HTML source and the tr highlighted that I want to grab.

[screenshot of HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fjqI.jpg)

The issue is the method of finding the table row data. Could someone please explain to me how to get other rows of data? It would be much appreciated !

Comment: [JPs IE Automation Tips](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/an-exploration-of-ie-browser-methods-part-ii/) have helped tremendously in exploring how to scrape data from webpages in VBA. There is code in there to loop through elements which you can then use `debug.print` to figure out which one you need.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The link you provide no longer works. Is there another source for it?

Comment: @RickHenderson - Yes, that website has been taken down. There are plenty of resources on the web if you search a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do some trial and error and to get the correct reference this way:

```
Dim eTR As Object, cTR As Object, I as Integer 'I used object, because I did late binding
Set cTR = Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")

i = 0

For Each eTR In cTR

    If Left(eTR.innerText, 3) = "Com" Then

        Debug.Print "(" & i; "): " & eTR.innerText

    End If

    i = i + 1

Next
```

The immediate window then displayed

> (308): Common Stocks ... (a bunch of space) ...
>   $5,941$5,877$5,773$3,779

I then tested this statement:

```
sd = Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(308).innerText
Debug.Print sd
```

And got the same result.